# Ansible AWX LDAP user search issue when users are members of a group

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

My ansible AWX exists in a domain.dev domain. I am trying to configure ldap access from ansible awx (tower). The following default "ldap user search" works.

```
[
 "OU=Admins,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev",
 "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
 "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"
]
```

However, we have security groups which contain users from another trusted domain. Those users must be able to login so "ldap user search" should search for users in all groups in an OU or specific groups depending on what is possible.

```
[ 
  "MemberOf=CN=DEVOPS,OU=Groups,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev", 
  "SCOPE_SUBTREE", 
  "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)" 
]
```

awx_web log returns:

```
INVALID_CREDENTIALS({'msgtype': 97, 'msgid': 1, 'result': 49, 'desc': 'Invalid credentials', 'ctrls': [], 'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563'}
```

"LDAP group type" is set to "NestedMemberDNGroupType".

The ldap host is a global catalog and I'm using port 3268.

Unfortunately I don't know any ldap experts, so any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd ldap search parameters are wrong, the 1st line must be a base dn while you provide a filter. Do you have an example of a user entry (dn) which is member of CN=DEVOPS,OU=Groups,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev ?

Comment: Hi @EricLavault. DN for the group is "CN=DEVOPS,OU=Groups,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev". Members are from the prod domain (ex. my.username in folder domain prod). So CN=my.username and DC=prod I guess. It should search for all  users in a group though, not just a single user.

Comment: Yes but you need first to provide a user base dn to find them, suppose they all have their dn ending with `OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev`, then this should be the first line of the search parameter. I don't know ansible but I would then add the membership filter on the third line, like `(&(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)(memberOf=CN=DEVOPS,OU=Groups,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev))`. Note also that you can provide multiple search queries.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault. I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I found more information on the members via LDAPExplorerTool. 

Group(s):
"CN=ADMINS,OU=Groups,OU=Dev,DC=domain,DC=dev"

Members:
"CN=S-1-5-21-xxx,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=dev"

It seems the member names are not resolved and I am beginning to think it won't be possible to login with user from another trusted domain (domain.prod). 

This one is difficult.

Comment: Btw... users from domain.prod can remote desktop into hosts reciding in domain.dev if the security group is added in windows local administrator group.